# What type of semi - martingale is local time?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $W(t)$ be a Wienner process. Let's define local time as

$$L_t(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow0^+}\frac{1}{2 \epsilon}\int_0^t \chi_{\{|W(s) - x| \le\epsilon\}} ds$$

I want to check weather this object is supermartingale, martingale or submartingale.

The hint is to use Tanak's formula:

$$|W(t) - t|= |x|  + \int_0^t\text{sign}(W(s) - x)dW(s)+L_t(x)$$

I tried to do it by definition i.e. to show that $E[L_{t+h} \mid \mathbb{F}_t] = L_t$, but I had no idea how to rewrite this conditional expected value. My second idea was more tricky - to use Ito formula ale see what's the expression in $dt$, however I also end up with nothing and with no idea how the Tanak's formula can be used for simplicity. Could you please give me a hint in which direction should I follow and in which moment Tanak's formula should be used ?

**EDIT**

I just have several questions about things that I don't fully get.

By facts that $W$ is a local martingale and $\text{sign}(W-x)$ is bounded predictable process you concluded that $H_t$ is local martingale. Could you please tell me to which exactly theorem you are referring to ? I'm afraid that I don't know such.

The second this is that you are rewriting expected value of quadratic variation of $H$:

$$E[(\int_0^t\text{sign}(W_s - x)dWs)^2] = E[\int_0^t \text{sign}(W_s -x)^2dt]$$

This equality is just direct application of Ito Isometry theorem. Now, because $\text{sign}(W_s - x)$ takes value $1$ almost everywhere (it doesn't take it for such $x: W_s = x$) we have that $E[H] = t$. But how this proves that $H_t$ is a martingale ? I was seeking for such theorem but wasn't able to find.

Comment: Well from the first representation you should see that this process is increasing right ?  So it's not a martingale.Second you should rephrase your question as What type of semi-martingale is local time ?

Comment: Hi @TheBridge, thank you very much for your comment. I agree with you ;)) I updated my title to be more self-comprehensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct Tanak's formula is given by
$$|W_t - x|= |x|  + \int_0^t\text{sign}(W_s - x)\Bbb dW_s+L_t(x).$$
As $W$ is a local martingale and $\text{sign}(W-x)$ is a bounded predictable process the stochastic integral $H_t:=\int_0^t\text{sign}(W_s - x)\Bbb dW_s$ is a local martingale. By using the generalized Itô-isometrie ($[.]$ denotes the quadratic variation)
$$\forall t\geq0:\Bbb E[H]_t=\Bbb E\int_0^t\text{sign}(W_s - x)^2 \Bbb ds=t<\infty,
$$
$H$ is a martingale. Furthermore $|W - x|$ is a submartingale, as by Jensen's inequality follows
$$\Bbb E\big(|W_t - x|\big|{\cal F_s}\big)\geq \Bbb |E\big(W_t - x\big|{\cal F_s}\big)|=|W_s - x|.
$$ Altogether
$$L_t(x)= |W_t - x| - \int_0^t\text{sign}(W_s - x)\Bbb dW_s-|x|$$
is for each $x$ the difference of a submartingale and a martingale, thus it is a submartingale.

Comment: Hi @mag, thank you very much for your answer - really appreciate that. I just have a few questions to you just to be as formal as possible. Could you please explain why $H_t$ is a local martingale and $E[\int_0^t sign(W_s -x)^2ds] = t$ ? Also expanding how Jensen's  inequality imply that $|W-x|$ is a submartingle would be great!

Comment: @Lucian: I updated the answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with my thoughts. Could you please dispel my doubts ?

Comment: The theorems don't have special names. But they are well known in stochastic analysis. If you don't know them yet, you can find them e.g. in the book of Protter Ch.IV.2 Th.29 (for the first one) and Ch.II.6 Cor.3 (for the second one).

Comment: Okay I will try to find them. Thank you very much for your time!